# Can not connect to SAP HANA with neo: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext

Tags: hana

I tried to use neo v3.186.6 (for the tunnel) and a Jetbrains integrated DB viewer to access a HANA database.

Upon establishing the connection I get the error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use Java 8, but the SAP 0002767581 note which would have told you is hidden behind a paywall and not indexed by search engines:

https://me.sap.com/notes/0002767581

You can download OpenJDK8 and then set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to the respective directory. On windows you might need to restart re-login after setting the env variable.

Comment: JAXB is no longer included with the JRE since Java 9. It is entirely possible that it will also work on higher Java versions **if** you include a JAXB 2.3.x library on the classpath.